# setting RuntimeHook on karate from scala/gatling side

Tags: java, karate

All our karate features being executed as integration tests got a RuntimeHook implementation.
Now I see that they are also called from Scala for performance testing and cannot figure out how to set the same RuntimeHook on them.
Is it possible at all? Did I miss something?

Java snippet from an integration test:

```
   @Karate.Test
   Karate karateFeatureTest() {
        return Karate.run("classpath:karate/somedir/a.feature").hook(new KarateHook());
    }
```

Scala snippet:

```
  val myVar: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test scenario")
    .exec(karateFeature("classpath:karate/somedir/a.feature"))
```

While the Karate class has a 'hook' method, karateFeature scala method doesn't have a parameter for a hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, here is the relevant documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#runner

Comment: Yey, looks like that's it - protocol.runner has a 'hook' method! Thanks!